# Using Countifs to get the number of items in a date range

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets to give me the total number of candidates being recruited from different sites in a date range. I am getting a *formula parse error* from:

```
=COUNTIFS('Candidates being recruited'!$G$2:$G$1000,$A4,'Candidates being recruited'!$K$2:$K$1000">11/1/2015",'Candidates being recruited'!$K$2:$K$1000"<11/7/2015")
```

**Candidates being recruited** is the tab I am pulling from.

- **$G$2:$G$1000** is the site listings
- **$A4** is the specific site name
- **$K$2:$K$1000"** is the date column

then I am listing the date range I am looking for.

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put a comma between the second and third range and condition as it needs the two and can't take an array of TRUE/FALSE values.
This formula approach with `Candidates being recruited'!$K$2:$K$1000">11/1/2015"` would be possible with array formulas but unnecessarily verbose.

Try

```
=COUNTIFS('Candidates being recruited'!$G$2:$G$1000,$A4,
          'Candidates being recruited'!$K$2:$K$1000,">11/1/2015",
          'Candidates being recruited'!$K$2:$K$1000,"<11/7/2015")
```

Comment: That worked! I know it was something simple that I was overlooking. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can I change the date to be a cell and not type the date? Will that still work with the formula the way it is?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate the condition like this: `"<"&A5` for example. Also if this solution helped you can you please accept the answer? Thank you.